# HTML5 database value won't stay on close of browser

Tags: html, local-storage

I am  trying to create a very basic html5 storage functionality and I have written the following code and it works.

JS:

```
function initDatabase() {
    try {
    alert("Hi");
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
        } else {
            var shortName = 'SOMEDB';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'SOMEDB';
            var maxSize = 10000; //  bytes
            SOMEDB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            createTables();
            //selectAll();
        }
    } catch(e) {
        if (e == 2) {
            // Version number mismatch.
            console.log("Invalid database version.");
        } else {
            console.log("Unknown error "+e+".");
        }
        return;
    }
}

function createTables(){
alert("Create table");
    SOMEDB.transaction(
        function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page_settings(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, settingname TEXT NOT NULL,value TEXT NOT NULL);', [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler);
        }
    );
    prePopulate();
}

function prePopulate(){
alert("In pre populating");
    SOMEDB.transaction(
        function (transaction) {
        //Optional Starter Data when page is initialized
        var setting1 = ['1','setting1','setting2'];
        transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO page_settings(id, settingname, value) VALUES ('1', 'bluetooth', 'on');",[],nullDataHandler, errorHandler);
        transaction.executeSql("commit;");
        }
    );
}

function errorHandler(transaction, error){
    if (error.code==1){
        // DB Table already exists
    } else {
        // Error is a human-readable string.
        console.log('Oops.  Error was '+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
    }
    return false;
}


function nullDataHandler(){
    console.log("SQL Query Succeeded");
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="db.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="initDatabase();">aa</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works. Once i click the href on my html page I can see the table created and the value is getting inserted. **But as soon as I close my browser and reopen it the data vanishes.**

Somehow it looks like the data is saved only in session. What am I doing wrong here?

I have uploaded similar code at this location. Can someone try this and let me know if this works for anyone. For me same problem,Data gets saved. I restart browser and data gone.
http://classictutorials.com/CTFiles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for putting there helping hands forward. I figured out what was wrong. Basically if you insert something in the table and then close and open the browser and then inspect with the browser inspector the data wont show up as the db connection is not opened yet. The inspector will show the DB but inside it it will be blank. The inspector will only be able to show you the data when you have opened the connection using any script. So the data is actually there but only not available to browser inspector on restart. I have written a script to open the db and read the table and am able to read the old data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I believe it is due to your code being local and not online. Try adding it to a server somewhere and accessing it remotely.

Comment: You are right I guess but I believe it should work on a web server, no matter local or remote. Maybe he is just trying to run the HTML file without a web server at all. I think you already meant that but remote server shouldn't be necessery, right?

Comment: Ya i tried that also.. i added it to my blog and same problem

Comment: Here is the link for my blog where i hosted it for testing http://classictutorials.com/CTFiles/

Comment: Yes I did mean any server, sorry I was not too clear.
I also put it on my own server:
http://www.kevinroseworld.com/RandomStuff/carbon.html
It seams like this kind of DB is not supported in Firefox v8.0 but is in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of rewriting your script. I hope you don't mind. This persists past closing the page. I otherwise used exactly the same html. I simply saw what I felt was a better way to do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var exampledb = {};
  exampledb.somedb = {};
  exampledb.somedb.db = null

  exampledb.somedb.open = function() {
    try {
      alert("Hi");
      if (!window.openDatabase) alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
      else {
        var shortName = 'SOMEDB',
        version = '1.0',
        displayName = 'SOMEDB',
        maxSize = 10240; //  10 kbytes
        exampledb.somedb.db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      if (e == 2) console.log("Invalid database version.");
      else console.log("Unknown error "+e+".");
      return;
    }
  }

  exampledb.somedb.createTable = function() {
    var db = exampledb.somedb.db;
    alert("Create Table");
    db.transaction( function(tx){
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page_settings(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, settingname TEXT NOT NULL,value TEXT NOT NULL);', [], exampledb.somedb.onSuccess, exampledb.somedb.onError );
    });
  }

  exampledb.somedb.prePopulate = function() {
    var db = exampledb.somedb.db;
    alert("In pre populating");
    db.transaction( function(tx) {
      var setting1 = ['1','bluetooth','on'];
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO page_settings(id, settingname, value) VALUES (?,?,?);",[setting1[0],setting1[1],setting1[2]], exampledb.somedb.onSuccess, exampledb.somedb.onError );
    });
  }

  exampledb.somedb.onError = function(tx, e) {
    if(e.code == 1) return false;
    else console.log('Oops. Error was '+e.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
  }

  exampledb.somedb.onSuccess = function(tx, r) {
    console.log( "SQL Query Succeeded" );
  }

  function initDatabase() {
    exampledb.somedb.open();
    if( exampledb.somedb.createTable() ) exampledb.somedb.prePopulate();
    else alert( "Table already exists!" );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks every one for putting there helping hands forward. I figured out what was wrong. Basically if you insert something in the table and then close and open the browser and then inspect with the browser inspector the data wont show up as the db connection is not opened yet. The inspector will show the DB but inside it it will be blank. The inspector will only be able to show you the data when you have opened the connection using any script.

Comment: Unfortunately, your original code did not maintain the database entries. Even if the connection was reestablished, your entries didn't persist. I suspect you may have been overwriting them.